# google analytics doesn't show the active user in Real time overview

Tags: android, google-analytics

i have setup every thing in my app for using `google analytics V4` 
and i get every things working and i can see it but when i go to real time overview in my mobile view i didn't see any active user

this is my tracker

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
  <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="info.lifepast.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>

    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxx-3</string>
</resources>
```

and the application class is

```
public class Analytics extends Application {
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxx-3";
  public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
    } 

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

          GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
          Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
              : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                  : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
          mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
      }
```

}

and in my main activity on create i added this

```
Tracker t = ((Analytics) this.getApplication()).getTracker(
        TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER);
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    // Set screen name.
    // Where path is a String representing the screen name.
    t.setScreenName(getString(R.string.app_name));

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

and the manifest file

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/global_tracker"/>
```

any help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been looking at the v4 analytics today, and have also had trouble getting screen views to post. Here are a couple things I've dug up during my investigations that may be helpful for you:

- `AppViewBuilder` is deprecated in favor of `ScreenViewBuilder` (see the `HitBuilders` source code). <strike>[This part](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#screen-view) of the documentation is, presumably, out of date.</strike> *Edit Mar 6, 2015: it would appear that the linked documentation has now been updated to use ScreenViewBuilder*.
- If my interpretation of the documentation is correct, it should not be necessary to explicitly post screen views using a `ScreenViewBuilder` when the auto activity tracking feature is enabled (which I see is the case in your configuration file).
- By default, the current date is not included in your Google Analytics stats. You can choose to include it by manually selecting a date range (see drop-down control at the top right of most GA pages).
- Make sure you shorten the dispatch period for debug builds - by default, events are batched and sent every 30 minutes, but for testing it's ok to reduce this to a few seconds. See the answer from @vangoz for implementation details.

Hope some of that helps you.

Edit: related, but I see you've already posted there: [Google Analytics API v4 for Android Does NOT Send Screen Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949303/google-analytics-api-v4-for-android-does-not-send-screen-views)

Comment: thx @stkent for your help but i m little confused now firstly i tried to replace the appviewrbuilder with screenviewrbuilder but as u said this wont work then i tried to remove this code bcuz of autotracking but it's also didn't work and when i was reading the reportactivity start doc they said that calling with with auto tracking is a noop but even thought i tried it with both auto tracking to true and false but same result

Comment: now i got it to work thanks stkent for your amazing description of the problem it's seems that realtime overview need some time to get what happens :D

Comment: Excellent, glad you got things worked out! Just fyi, the delay that occurs before events show up in the real-time view may be because [the default dispatch period is set to 30 minutes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch#periodic). Try shortening that if you want events to appear more quickly.

Comment: thanks @stkent this works too thanks for your great answer which help alot in seeing what the problem instead of copying code

Comment: This is insane. I made my app live with the code from the guides after testing yielded results, now nothing at all is being reported on GA. The guides seem to be terrible. Going to try this tomorrow and hope it's the way to go, trying something else today, but have to wait for GA to refresh at 4am everyday.. this is so annoying. Glad I found a post on this issue though.

Comment: No matter what I try there is absolutely no change in any GA view during the whole daytime - no real-time data, no overview. Only late after midnight at some point the data is updated but seem it still not all hits are reported. IMO real-time is silently disabled by Google for some reasons - maybe to minimize the server load.

Answer (score 6):

For me it turns out Google Analytics only dispatch the data every 30 minutes by default. So changing the dispatch time for testing show the realtime data with some delay.

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(15);
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch

Comment: I've hit the same thing and your post saved my sanity! Thank you. That is a truely ridiculous default setting.