# Real Time Google Analytics for My Android app not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

Recently I bought Android app from Market Source code, and I decide to add Google Analytics SDK to the app, and I configure the analytics.xml and also my Application Activity.Java.

But when I’m trying to use app at the same I check my Google Analytics account "No data".

Just to be clear, The app that I bought there's no `onStart()` or `onStop()`.  I decide to replace the Analytics code `EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);` in `onDestroy()` / `onResume()` .

But no single data.

I tried creating `onStart()`, `onStop()` ... and the same problem, I can't figure out why.

PS: the Google Analytics SDK library is added into my app.

Comment: May be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949983/google-analytics-doesnt-show-the-active-user-in-real-time-overview

Comment: I Try this before i post here, but nothing! Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime analytics data is not reflected instantly. 
Check after some time.

Comment: To add to this, I've noticed that "real time" Analytics is delayed by AT LEAST five minutes. Also, make sure you're checking the correct area in the dashboard.

Comment: More than 5 hours! I don't think. As i saw in some tutorials analytics data was showing instantly.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound insane, but the only change I did was removed the empty line between android{} and dependencies{} blocks in the build.grade file. If this helps anyone, I will be surprised as the problem could not be reproduced.